# Problems passing struct pointers and "conflicting types" errors

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, compiler-errors

I am writing a program that permutes a list of names based on a given input. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 19 //names no longer than 19 chars
#define MAXPEOPLE 10

struct genderinfo {
    char** winning;
    char** names;
    int** scores;
};


char** allocnames(int num);
int** allocratings(int num, int num2);
void inputdata(int numpeople, struct genderinfo *male, struct genderinfo *female, FILE* fp);
void permute(int permuteset[], int k, int numpeople, struct genderinfo *male, struct     genderinfo *female, int *maxLindex);
void swap(int permuteset[],int i, int j);
void compare(int permuteset[], struct genderinfo *male, struct genderinfo *female, int *maxLindex, int numpeople);

///write free functions for struct arrays

int main () {

FILE* fp = fopen("matching.txt", "r");

struct genderinfo male;
struct genderinfo female;

//loop variables
int numdates, i, j, k;

//other variables
int numpeople, maxLindex = 0, difference;

fscanf(fp, "%d", &numdates);

for(i=1; i <= numdates; i++) {

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numpeople);
    //printf("%d possible couples\n", numpeople);

    //allocate memory for arrays of names
    male.names = allocnames(numpeople);
    female.names = allocnames(numpeople);
    male.winning = allocnames(numpeople);
    female.winning = allocnames(numpeople);

    //allocate memory for score arrays
    male.scores = allocratings(numpeople, numpeople);
    female.scores = allocratings(numpeople, numpeople);
    int permuteset[numpeople];

    //fill permute set with 0-k, these will serve as array indexes to compare against malenames array
    //format used will be malenames[i][permuteset[i]] femalenames[permuteset[i]][i] to index the scores
    for(k=0; k<numpeople; k++)
        permuteset[k] = k;

    inputdata(numpeople, &male, &female, fp);
    permute(permuteset, 0, numpeople, &male, &female &maxLindex);

    printf("Matching #%d: Maximum Score = %d\n\n", i, maxLindex);

    for (j=0; j<numpeople; j++){

            printf("%s %s\n", male.winning[j], female.winning[j]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

}

return 0;

}

char** allocnames(int num) {

int i;

char** names = (char**)malloc(num*sizeof(char*));

for(i=0; i < num; i++)
    names[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN+1);

return names;

}

int** allocratings(int num, int num2) {

int i;

int** ratings = (int**)malloc(num*sizeof(int*));

for(i=0; i < num; i++)
    ratings[i] = (int*)malloc(num2*sizeof(int));

return ratings;

}

void inputdata(int numpeople, struct genderinfo *male, struct genderinfo *female, FILE* fp) {

int i, j;

for (i=0; i < numpeople; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", male->names[i]);
    //printf("%s ", malenames[i]);
}

for (i=0; i < numpeople; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", female->names[i]);
    //printf("%s ", femalenames[i]);
}

for (i=0; i < numpeople; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < numpeople; j++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &male->scores[i][j]);
        //printf("%d ", malescores[i]);
    }
}

for (i=0; i < numpeople; i++) {
    for(j=0; j < numpeople; j++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &female->scores[i][j]);
        //printf("%d ", femalescores[i][j]);
    }
}
}

void permute(int permuteset[], int k, int numpeople, struct genderinfo *male, struct genderinfo *female, int *maxLindex) {

int i;

if (k == numpeople) {

    compare(permuteset, &male, &female, &maxLindex, numpeople);
}

else {

     // Loop through each possible starting letter for index k,
     // the first index for which we have a choice.
     for (i=k; i<numpeople; i++) {

         // Place the character stored in index j in location k.
         swap(permuteset, k, i);

         // Print out all of the permutations with that character
         // just chosen above fixed.
         permute(permuteset, 0, numpeople, &male, &female &maxLindex);

         // Put the original character that used to be there back
         // in its place.
         swap(permuteset, i, k);
     } //end i for
 } //end else

}

void swap(int permuteset[], int i, int j) {

int temp = permuteset[i];
permuteset[i] = permuteset[j];
permuteset[j] = temp;

}

//This function will take a permutation in and compare malescores[i] to
//femalescores[permuteset[i]]
//if malescores[i] > femalescores[permuteset[i]] scoresum += bla blah else if.... etc.

//copy malenames[i] and femalenames[permuteset[i]] into winning couples
//with if statements above

//malescores[i][permuteset[i]]
//femalescores[permuteset[i]][i]]
void compare(int permuteset[], struct genderinfo *male, struct genderinfo *female, int *maxLindex, int numpeople) {

int temp_maxLindex, i, j, minlike;

for(i=0; i<numpeople; i++){

    if (male->scores[i][permuteset[i]] > female->scores[permuteset[i]][i])
        minlike = female->scores[permuteset[i]][i];

    else
        minlike = male->scores[permuteset[i]][i];

    temp_maxLindex += minlike;

    if (temp_maxLindex > maxLindex) {
        maxLindex = temp_maxLindex;

        for(j=0; j<numpeople; j++){

            strcpy(male->winning[j], male->names[i]);
            strcpy(female->winning[j], female->names[permuteset[i]]);

        } //j for

    } //if

} //i for

}
```

I am getting these errors, one having to do with what im passing into my inputdata function, and a bunch of others about conflicting types?? I have been tinkering around with the code for a bit now and can't get anywhere. At this point I'm just trying to get the code to run so I can debug the algorithm and whatnot, any help is appreciated greatly.

```
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c||In function 'main':|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|61|error: invalid operands to binary & (have 'struct genderinfo *' and 'int')|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|61|error: too few arguments to function 'permute'|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|17|note: declared here|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|35|warning: unused variable 'difference' [-Wunused-variable]|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c||In function 'permute':|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|139|warning: passing argument 2 of 'compare' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|19|note: expected 'struct genderinfo *' but argument is of type 'struct genderinfo **'|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|139|warning: passing argument 3 of 'compare' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|19|note: expected 'struct genderinfo *' but argument is of type 'struct genderinfo **'|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|139|warning: passing argument 4 of 'compare' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|19|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|153|error: invalid operands to binary & (have 'struct genderinfo **' and 'int *')|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|153|warning: passing argument 4 of 'permute' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|133|note: expected 'struct genderinfo *' but argument is of type 'struct genderinfo **'|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|153|error: too few arguments to function 'permute'|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|133|note: declared here|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c||In function 'compare':|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|194|warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]|
D:\School\Summer 2012\CS1\Assignments\2\main.c|195|warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
||=== Build finished: 10 errors, 7 warnings ===|
```

Comment: You should include the code where you call the functions that are giving you the error - the permute() and compare() code. Include the specific error too.

Comment: Also adding full compiler output where the error is showing would help too!

Comment: I have added the full code with error messages. I have altered it to clean up the male and female arrays into structs. Take a look

Comment: First: put the struct definitions before the function declarations that use them.

Comment: oh wow, silly mistake. updated the errors in the post ha. Seems to be the same errors I originally had prior to consolidating the arrays to structs.

Comment: also found a missing comma in my permute() function calls. now its strictly the pointer problems (expected struct genderinfo* but type is of struct genderinfo**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--- permute.c.OLD   2012-06-14 22:48:06.760926525 +0200
+++ permute.c   2012-06-14 22:47:37.344810744 +0200
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@

 ///write free functions for struct arrays

-int main () {
+int main (void) {

 FILE* fp = fopen("matching.txt", "r");

@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
 int numdates, i, j, k;

 //other variables
-int numpeople, maxLindex = 0, difference;
+int numpeople, maxLindex = 0; // difference;

 fscanf(fp, "%d", &numdates);

@@ -58,7 +58,7 @@
         permuteset[k] = k;

     inputdata(numpeople, &male, &female, fp);
-    permute(permuteset, 0, numpeople, &male, &female &maxLindex);
+    permute(permuteset, 0, numpeople, &male, &female, &maxLindex);

     printf("Matching #%d: Maximum Score = %d\n\n", i, maxLindex);

@@ -136,7 +136,7 @@

 if (k == numpeople) {

-    compare(permuteset, &male, &female, &maxLindex, numpeople);
+    compare(permuteset, male, female, maxLindex, numpeople);
 }

 else {
@@ -150,7 +150,7 @@

          // Print out all of the permutations with that character
          // just chosen above fixed.
-         permute(permuteset, 0, numpeople, &male, &female &maxLindex);
+         permute(permuteset, 0, numpeople, male, female, maxLindex);

          // Put the original character that used to be there back
          // in its place.
@@ -191,8 +191,8 @@

     temp_maxLindex += minlike;

-    if (temp_maxLindex > maxLindex) {
-        maxLindex = temp_maxLindex;
+    if (temp_maxLindex > *maxLindex) {
+        *maxLindex = temp_maxLindex;

         for(j=0; j<numpeople; j++){
```

Summary: missing kommaas, too many ampersands, missing asterixes.

I have not checked for semantic errors, I presume they are still present. (the unbounded recursive call in permute() looks suspect)

I also advise to remove the casts from malloc()s return value and use the idiom `p = malloc N * sizeof *p);` But that would increase the size of the diff even more.

Comment: So it is illegal to pass by reference in a function after passing parameters by reference in main? I assume it's because youre essentially passing a references "reference"? (which doesnt exist).  so taking into account what I said above it means within functions that you've already passed variables into by reference you merely use the pointer as you illustrated in that last correction you posted?

Comment: I'm afraid you don't really understand pointers. (Or I misunderstood your intentions) For main, the "male" and "female" objects are structs. It can pass them to the other functions by pointer, using `func( &male);` The recieving function sees them as pointers (say : pmale). If the recieving function wants to call itself recursively, it are already pointers, so it can still use `func( pmale );`. No ampersands needed, (unless you want the recursive function to change the pointer, which makes no sense to me at the moment) The functions in question are permute() and compare() BTW.

Comment: Cool I was thinking along those lines. Thank you for the help and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing here as the code that is causing the error is not given by you at time of posting this, but as the list of your parameters to these functions

```
void permute(int permuteset[], int k, int numpeople, char** winningmales, char** winningfemales, char** malenames, char** femalenames, int** malescores,
         int** femalescores, int *maxLindex);

void compare(int permuteset[], char** winningmales, char** winningfemales, char** malenames, char** femalenames, int** malescores, int**femalescores,
         int *maxLindex, int numpeople);
```

is very large and as you report an error between an `int*` and `int**` I wonder if you have accidentally got the order of your arguments wrong in the places that you call the above functions???

As I say this is only a guess but it might be worth investigating.

Comment: Since you're passing the same info for both genders, you could group the parallel items into a struct and make the function call less typo-prone:  `struct gender_info { char** winning; char** names; int** scores; }`.  With that structure, your functions would take 6 arguments instead of 10.

Comment: I think you will need to include some code of where you call the functions that give you the error.

Comment: I've edited and posted the full code into the original post. The issue now is similar, but with errors with the inputdata function as well as "conflicting types" problems.